# Running time of 3 nested for-loops, where the innermost loop depends on the operations in the outer loop (not an obvious case)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, nested-loops

I'm a beginner here studying algorithms for the first time. I'd like to know the running time of the following algorithm with 3 nested for loops. I know in most cases it's the lengths of the loops multiplied. However, in this case, the length of the innermost loop depends on the operation outside of the loop.

```c
def loops(n,k){
  exp = 1;
  for (i=0; i<n; i++){
    newexp =0;
    for (j=0; j<k; j++){
      for (q =0; q<exp; q++){
        newexp++;
      }
    }
    exp = newexp;
  }
  return exp;
}
```

My guess is that since `exp` increases exponentially for each iteration of *i*, it's O(n*k*(k^n)). Am I getting this right? Any explanation would be appreciated. Thank you all!!

Answer (score 1):

First some comments on the pseudo code:

- `a` is not used, so would not be needed as parameter.
- `k` is nowhere defined; it probably should be a parameter as you also use it as a variable in the complexity calculation.

Here is a diagram with a row for each iteration of the outer loop, and the state just before `exp = newexp;` is executed

|  |  | := ∙ | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |  |  |
| 1 |  | ² | +² |
| 2 | ² | ³ | +²+³ |
| ... | ... | ... | .... |
| −1 | <sup>−1</sup> |  | ∑<sub>=1..</sub> |

The last column represents the number of times `newexp++` is executed which is the determining factor for asymptotic complexity when both  and  grow indefinitely. The accumulated value represents a [sum of a geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum) (without the first term 1), and is:

(<sup>+1</sup>−1) / (−1) − 1

This is O()